# In C#, is it possible to check files in certain FTP folder and upload the ones that aren't there?

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I want to write a C# that:

1. Access the FTP with username and password
2. Goes to a certain folder
3. Sees what files aren't there from my PC folder and upload them.

My idea:
I have a folder called "mods" in my PC and another folder called "mods" in the FTP, so instead of opening the "FileZilla" software I want to write a C# that connects to the FTP and check what files aren't there.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

you can list your file inftp server like this and do a comparaiosn with list file of mod dir

```
  FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
  ftpRequest.Credentials =new NetworkCredential("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");
  ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
  FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
  StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

  List<string> directories = new List<string>();

  string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
  while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
  {
      directories.Add(line);
      line = streamReader.ReadLine();
  }

  streamReader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no magic way, with a pure .NET framework (its [`FtpWebRequest` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest)). You have to code it.

- List the FTP folder
- List the local folder
- Find the missing files
- Upload them one by one

```
void SynchronizeLocalAndFtpDirectory(
         string localPath, string remoteUri, NetworkCredential credentials)
{
    List<string> remoteFiles = new List<string>();

    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUri);
    request.Credentials = credentials;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            remoteFiles.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<string> localFiles =
        Directory.GetFiles(localPath).Select(path => Path.GetFileName(path));

    IEnumerable<string> missingFiles = localFiles.Except(remoteFiles);

    foreach (string filename in missingFiles)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uploading missing file {0}", filename);
        string remoteFileUri = remoteUri + filename;
        string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, filename);
        FtpWebRequest uploadRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteFileUri);
        uploadRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        uploadRequest.Credentials = credentials;

        using (Stream targetStream = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream())
        using (Stream sourceStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10240];
            int read;
            while ((read = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                targetStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use the function like:

```
SynchronizeLocalAndFtpDirectory(
    @"C:\local\mods", "ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/mods/",
    new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));
```

(Do not forget the trailing slash in the URI).

---

Or use 3rd party FTP library that supports synchronization.

For example with the [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library), this is as easy as a single call to [`Session.SynchronizeDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_synchronizedirectories).

And it will not only upload missing file, but also update out-of-the-date files and optionally delete orphan files.

```
void SynchronizeLocalAndFtpDirectory(
         string localPath, string remotePath, SessionOptions sessionOptions)
{
    using (Session session = new Session())
    {
        session.Open(sessionOptions);

        session.SynchronizeDirectories(
            SynchronizationMode.Remote, localPath, remotePath, false).Check();
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions()
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.example.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "password",
};

SynchronizeLocalAndFtpDirectory(@"C:\local\mods", "/remote/mods", sessionOptions);
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*